# Powershell - Launch File Explorer UNC Path

Tags: powershell

I'm new to posh and i'd like to create a script for our service desk where they'll be able to access unc share (like \computername\c$) without entering credentials. This works perfectly :

```
$share = '\\servername\c$\Tools'
$UserName = 'contoso\john'
$Password = 'P@ssword'|ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName,$Password
New-PSDrive -Name B -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $share -Credential $cred -Persist
Invoke-Expression "explorer '/select,$share'" 
Remove-PSDrive -Name B
```

I'm trying to implement an inputbox but it doesn't work :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
$serverName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter ComputerName ", "Accessing C$ Share", $Default, $Form.Left + 300, $Form.Top + 100)
```

cause the value doesn't get implemented :

```
$share = '\\$servername\c$\Tools'
```

Can someone tell me why ? and how to solve it ? Thanks for your help

Comment: *"cause the value doesn't get implemented :"*  this tells us nothing. Please update your post with any errors and tell us what actually happens vs what you'd like to happen.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: sorry for the format i tried but didn't succeed...

Comment: doug : there's no error, when i enter a computername in my inputbox and then typed down $share in powershell to check the value it stayed to $share = '\\$servername\c$\Tools' instead of \\ABC01\xxxx, fortunately @esperanto gave me the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your simple quote by double quote like this, othewise Powershell dont evaluate your string :

```
$share = "\\$servername\c$\Tools"
```

You can use -f too for build your string :

```
$share='\\{0}\c$\Tools' -f $serverName
```

Comment: You're a King :) been searchin' for days ! Thanks a lot ! Would you mind to explain me what means -f ?

Comment: Happy for you. -f is the format operator. You find detail here : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx